# HTTP Handler to Handle .zips

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http, arrays, handler

I have a handler that handles single files (text based) perfectly. I can receive .zip files but they are unable to be accessed due to "corruption" errors. I know that this is due to reading things in as a text stream and not a byte array but I cannot figure it out. (My attempt is below)

EDIT:
I need to be able to have the handler accept .zips without corruption errors. I got past the corruption errors but the below code handles the file without corruption issues but unzips it with no files inside.

```
    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context as HttpContent) Implements IHTTPHandler.ProcessRequest

    Try
    If Context.Request.HttpMethod() = "POST" Then
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    context.Response.StatusCode = 204
    Dim reader as New System.IO.BinaryReader(context.Request.InputStream)
    Dim contents as Byte
    Dim int as Integer = reader.Basestream.Length

 ''Problem has got to be here, This loop structure can't be right..
    Do While int > 0
    contents = reader.readByte()
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("thisismyoutputdirectory"), filename), contents)
    Loop
        else
    ''Handle non post cases
    end if

    Catch ex as Exception
    ''Error Handling is here
    End Try

    End Sub
```

Instead of `Streamreader` I am using `BinaryReader`. I have attempted to save contents as a byte array and then write them all out using the `WriteAllBytes` method.

I will continue experiementing but any guidance would be great!

Comment: The contentType must be change from text.

Comment: @Aristos I tried that by changing it to octet. I think my syntax is just off I will post when i get a chance.

Comment: Post here the actual code that you try to send as zip, not the other that is still text.

Comment: I am confuse - You read the `Request.InputStream` and try to send it back as zip. Do you have the file you won to send inside a file or what is this that you try to send `Request.InputStream`

Comment: @ Aristos Thanks for the help. I figured out the issue and my answer is below. Feel free to sum up my answer and add any additional info you may have. I would like to reward you with some rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue. I simply needed to write it out to a byte array and save an integer to represent the number of bytes. Then simply print the contents. It looks like I was trying to make things more complicated.

My loop in original code is kinda ugly :(

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context as HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

Try

   ''If the handler receives a POST requent then perform these actions    
    If context.Request.HttpMethod() = "POST" Then
      context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-Stream"
      context.Response.StatusCode = 204
      ''Get the filename out of the requests header
      Dim filename as String = context.Request.Header("filename")
      ''Get the numbytes for the .zip and save them as a byte array
      Dim numbytes as Integer = reader.BaseStream.Length
      Dim contents() as Byte = reader.ReadBytes(numbytes)
     ''Write the byte array out to the file
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("This/is/my/path/" & filename, contents)
    else
    '' Handle has no work to do since request was not a POST
    End if

    Catch
    ''Error Handling is here
    End Try
```